# Why is lodash _.get(jsonObject: JsonObject, path: "somePath") behaving differently after update?

Tags: typescript, lodash, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I'm trying to update some CDK that's in Typescript (as part of migrating from CDK v1 to v2). I updated a bunch of typescript and node dependencies, as well as AWS-specific dependencies, but I have a pretty simple block that is breaking, and I'm not sure why.

Here's the relevant snippet:

```
    private createScheduleRule(scope: Construct, invocationRule: JsonObject, props: ScheduleProps): events.Rule {
        const rule = _.get(invocationRule, "Rule");
        return new events.Rule(scope, `${rule["name"]}Rule`, {
            enabled: !_.get(invocationRule, "Disabled", false),
            schedule: rule["expression"].startsWith("P")
                ? events.Schedule.rate(cdk.Duration.parse(rule["expression"]))
                : events.Schedule.expression(`cron(${rule["expression"]})`)
            ...
        }
```

JsonObject is defined as:

```
export type JsonObject = string | number | boolean | JsonObject[] | { readonly [key: string]: JsonObject };
```

I can post the versions if anyone thinks it might help troubleshoot. I didn't update the version of lodash in my package.json (^4.17.14)

The error I'm getting is that "rule" might be undefined. If I try to get around it by adding `!` so when I use `rule` I go `${rule!["name"]}Rule` for example, I get around the error, but it doesn't work for `rule!["expression"].startsWith("P")` - it says `startsWith` doesn't exist on the `never` type.

Besides, this doesn't seem like the right solution, and I'm not sure why the type for "rule" is getting inferred as `undefined` in my IDE and when I build instead of `any` like it was before. In my IDE, when I try to get which `.get` overload it's using, it says it's using:

```
        get<TObject, TPath extends string>(data: TObject, path: TPath): string extends TPath ? any : GetFieldType<TObject, TPath>;
```

now, when in my IDE before my typescript and CDK updates it was getting:

```
        get(object: any, path: PropertyPath, defaultValue?: any): any;
```

of the `LodashStatic` interface.

Any help troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated. If anyone has run into anything similar, please let me know!